# Subquery in MS-Access SQL Syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access

Good Evening.

I'm trying to create a query that averages each product purchase Vs. the number of purchases to get the average amount purchased.

This includes three tables:

1. CUSTOMER
2. INVOICE
3. LINE

**I wrote this:**

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE, CUS_FNAME+" "+CUS_LNAME AS Name, CUSTOMER.CUS_BALANCE,    
Sum([LINE]![LINE_NUMBER]*[LINE]![LINE_PRICE]) AS Total_purchases,  
Count(INVOICE.INV_NUMBER) AS Number_of_purchases, 

(
SELECT [Sum([LINE]![LINE_NUMBER]*[LINE]![LINE_PRICE]) /   
[Count(INVOICE.INV_NUMBER)]
FROM INVOICE, LINE
WHERE INVOICE.INV_NUMBER = LINE.INV_NUMBER
) AS Average_purchase_amount

FROM CUSTOMER, INVOICE, LINE
WHERE CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE = INVOICE.CUS_CODE AND INVOICE.INV_NUMBER = LINE.INV_NUMBER 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE, CUS_FNAME+" "+CUS_LNAME, CUSTOMER.CUS_BALANCE;
```

---

I get an error at the second SELECT. I'm not sure why. I feel like I'm missing something very simple.

**The actual error reads:**

- "Syntax error in query expression '(
   SELECT [Sum([LINE]![LINE_NUMBER]*[LINE]![LINE_PRICE]) / [Count(INVOICE.INV_NUMBER)].'"

From the error I assume that somewhere in my expression things are not lining up, but I guess I don't understand enough about what is going on to know what exactly it is.

Comment: Please do not change the subject by editing your question like that.  If your original question was about a syntax error, you can answer it yourself or accept the answer given by Vincent.  If you have a different problem, ask a new question.  Remember, this is a "question and answer" site, not a discussion board.

Comment: @BellevueBob Sorry I'll delete things.

Comment: Better, thanks!  This keeps your original question relevant, in case someone visits it again in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are unbalanced brackets.  Either each one was meant to be in brackets or whole equation:

```
SELECT [Sum([LINE]![LINE_NUMBER]*[LINE]![LINE_PRICE])] / [Count(INVOICE.INV_NUMBER)]
```

-- OR --

```
SELECT [Sum([LINE]![LINE_NUMBER]*[LINE]![LINE_PRICE]) /  Count(INVOICE.INV_NUMBER)]
```

Try JOINing your tables.  Something like this:

```
FROM INVOICE
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE = INVOICE.CUS_CODE
    INNER JOIN LINE ON LINE.INV_NUMBER =INVOICE.INV_NUMBER
```

Comment: Personally I just too the brackets away and it worked, but introduced a new problem with it having the same value for every customer...

Comment: Yes the brackets are optional, but if you use them you need to keep them balanced.  As far as the same values, it is your FROM statement.  You need to join the tables.